# Hit Location in SOLR When Indexing a Large Text

Tags: search, solr, pagination, lucene, nlp

We are creating a SOLR index of a corpus of digital books that are marked up in XML. The index is to be used for NLP analysis of the corpus as well as locating passages within the corpus. I am processing each text into a JSON solr doc for indexing and posting that to the index.

The XML of each book includes markers for all the page breaks in the text, each marked with a "milestone" tag. I have created the initial version of the index by stripping out all the milestones from the body of the text and dumping the text of whole book into a single field so that strings or passages that go over a page break can be found.

My question is: How can I determine the location of hits in a text (i.e. what page they are on) when a search is made?

Comment: A related question with answers is [Can Solr highlighting also indicate the position or offset of the returned fragments within the original field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863118/can-solr-highlighting-also-indicate-the-position-or-offset-of-the-returned-fragm). Seems like it is not possible without a custom Formatter.